# How to convert a multi line string input from an textbox (in a userform) to a single line input string (vba word)

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox, userform, multilinestring

I have created a user form on VBA (word) where the user inputs a body of multi line text into TextBox1. I wish to convert this into a single line string. I have tried the following:

```
'Replace method 
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace what:=vbFl replacement:=""
```

This results in 'invalid qualifier' with regards to the .Text

```
'Replace function
TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, vbLf, "")
```

This produces no error but doesn't carry out the required conversion.

Comment: Your second attempt has the correct syntax which is why it doesn't produce an error, but the What-string isn't found because vbLf is a long, not a string, and though VBA probably manages to coerce the number into a string it isn't a number you are looking for. Off the top of my head I don't know which string the TextBox uses. It could be Chr(10) or Chr(11) or perhaps Chr(10) & Chr(13) - or the other way around. You can enter this like `What:=Chr(11)`

Comment: @Variatus `vbLF` is undoubtedly a string. It's just not the correct string to use in this context, apparently :) (Try `?TypeName(vbLF)` in the Immediate window if you'd like)

Comment: Thank you @David Zemens. Looks can be deceiving, then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word, you have to consider the carriage return as well. There are three ways doing it your way:

```
'Replace function
TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, vbCr + vbLf, "")
TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, Chr(10) + Chr(13), "")
TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, vbCrLf, "")
```